# Using java securityManager blocks me from reading files

Tags: java, exception, io, exit-code, securitymanager

In my java code I call another 3rd party java class.

I want to catch that latter `System.exit()` exit code

So I use security-manager as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549720/how-to-prevent-calls-to-system-exit-from-terminating-the-jvm)

The problem is that I cannot read files now, I get permissions error

as seen in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526263/accesscontrolexception-access-denied-for-a-readable-file).

How can I catch the exit code and still read files?

```
Published class MyClass {

class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new SecurityException();
    }
}

public void foo() {
    MySecurityManager secManager = new MySecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(secManager);

    try {
        ConfigValidator.main(new String[]{"-dirs", SdkServiceConfig.s.PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH});

        new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/sdk-service/src/main/resources/convert_conditions.sh"));


    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //Do something if the external code used System.exit()
        String a = "1";

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("failed converting properties file to proto", e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate problems: Your trusted code cannot read the file, while the untrusted third-party library can still call `System#exit` unhindered. The former can be easily circumvented by granting further privileges to the trusted code; the latter is a tad trickier to address.

#### A bit of background

**Privilege assignment**
Code (the `ProtectionDomain`s encapsulated by a thread's `AccessControlContext`) generally gets assigned `Permission`s in two ways: Statically, by the `ClassLoader`, upon class definition, and/or dynamically, by the `Policy` in effect. Other, less frequently encountered alternatives, exist as well: `DomainCombiner`s, for instance, can modify `AccessControlContext`s' domains (and therefore the effective permissions of their respective code that is subject to authorization) on the fly, and custom domain implementations may use their own logic for permission implication, possibly disregarding or altering the semantics of the policy. By default the permission set of a domain is the *union* of its static *and* dynamic permissions. As for how exactly classes are mapped to domains, it is, for the most part, up to the loader's implementation. By default, all classes, JAR'ed or otherwise, residing beneath the same class path entry, are grouped under the same domain. More restrictive class loaders may choose to e.g. allocate a domain per class, which could be used to prevent communication even between classes within the same package.

**Privilege evaluation**
Under the default `SecurityManager`, for a privileged operation (an invocation of any method having a `SecurityManager#checkXXX` within its body) to succeed, every domain (of every class of every method) of the effective `AccessControlContext` must have been assigned, as explained above, the permission being checked. Recall however that the context need not necessarily represent "the truth" (the actual call stack)—system code gets optimized away early on, while `AccessController#doPrivileged` calls, along with the `DomainCombiner` potentially coupled to the `AccessControlContext` can modify the context's domains, and the authorization algorithm in its entirety, consequently.

#### Problem and workarounds

The issue with `System#exit` is that the corresponding permission (`RuntimePermission("exitVM.*")`) is one amongst few that are *statically* assigned by the default application class loader (`sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`) to all domains associated with classes loaded from the class path.

A number of alternatives come to mind:

1. Installing a custom `SecurityManager` which denies the particular right based on, e.g., the class attempting to terminate the JVM process.
2. Loading the third-party library from a "remote" location (a directory outside of the class path), so that it gets treated as "untrusted" code by its class loader.
3. Authoring and installing a different application class loader, which does not assign the extraneous permission.
4. Plugging a custom domain combiner into the access control context, which replaces, at the time of an authorization decision, all third-party domains with equivalent ones that do not have the offending permission.

I should, for the sake of completeness, note that at the `Policy` level, unfortunately, nothing can be done to negate statically assigned permissions.

The first option is overall the most convenient one, but I will not explore it further because:

- The default `SecurityManager` is quite flexible, thanks to the handful of components (`AccessController` et al.) it interacts with. The background section in the beginning aimed to serve as a reminder of that flexibility, which "quick-n'-dirty" method overrides tend to cripple.
- Careless modifications of the default implementation might cause (system) code to misbehave in curious ways.
- Frankly, because it's boring―it's the one-size-fits-all solution perpetually advocated, while the fact that the default manager was standardized in 1.2 for a reason has long been forgotten.

The second alternative is easy to implement but impractical, complicating either development or the build process. Assuming you are not planning to invoke the library solely reflectively, or aided by interfaces present on the class path, it would have to be present initially, during development, and relocated before execution.

The third is, at least in the context of a standalone Java SE application, fairly straightforward and should not pose too much of a burden on performance. It is the approach I will favour herein.

The last option is the most novel and least convenient. It is hard to securely implement, has the greatest potential for performance degradation, and burdens client code with ensuring presence of the combiner prior to every delegation to untrusted code.

#### Proposed solution

**The custom `ClassLoader`**
The following is to be used as the replacement of the default application loader, or alternatively as the context class loader, or the loader used to load at least the untrusted classes. There is nothing novel to this implementation—all it does is prevent delegation to the default application class loader when the class in question is assumed to not be a system one. `URLClassLoader#findClass`, in turn, does not assign `RuntimePermission("exitVM.*")` to the domains of the classes it defines.

```
package com.example.trusted;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ClasspathClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private static final Pattern SYSTEM_CLASS_PREFIX = Pattern.compile("((java(x)?|sun|oracle)\\.).*");

    public ClasspathClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(new URL[0], parent);
        String[] classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator);
        for (String classpathEntry : classpath) {
            try {
                if (!classpathEntry.endsWith(".jar") && !classpathEntry.endsWith("/")) {
                    // URLClassLoader assumes paths without a trailing '/' to be JARs by default
                    classpathEntry += "/";
                }
                addURL(new URL("file:" + classpathEntry));
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                System.err.println(MessageFormat.format("Erroneous class path entry [{0}] skipped.", classpathEntry));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> ret;
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            ret = findLoadedClass(name);
            if (ret != null) {
                return ret;
            }
            if (SYSTEM_CLASS_PREFIX.matcher(name).matches()) {
                return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
            ret = findClass(name);
            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(ret);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

If you also wish to fine-tune the domains assigned to loaded classes, you will additionally have to override `findClass`. The following variant of the loader is a very crude attempt at doing so. `constructClassDomain` therein merely creates one domain per class path entry (which is more or less the default), but can be modified to do something different.

```
package com.example.trusted;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class ClasspathClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private static final Pattern SYSTEM_CLASS_PREFIX = Pattern.compile("((java(x)?|sun|oracle)\\.).*");
    private static final List<WeakReference<ProtectionDomain>> DOMAIN_CACHE = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor, loadClass same as above

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        URL classOrigin = getClassResource(name);
        if (classOrigin == null) {
            return super.findClass(name);
        }
        URL classCodeSourceOrigin = getClassCodeSourceResource(classOrigin);
        if (classCodeSourceOrigin == null) {
            return super.findClass(name);
        }
        return defineClass(name, readClassData(classOrigin), constructClassDomain(classCodeSourceOrigin));
    }

    private URL getClassResource(String name) {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<URL>) () -> getResource(name.replace(".", "/") + ".class"));
    }

    private URL getClassCodeSourceResource(URL classResource) {
        for (URL classpathEntry : getURLs()) {
            if (classResource.getPath().startsWith(classpathEntry.getPath())) {
                return classpathEntry;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private ByteBuffer readClassData(URL classResource) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(classResource.openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i;
            while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            return ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    private ProtectionDomain constructClassDomain(URL classCodeSourceResource) {
        ProtectionDomain ret = getCachedDomain(classCodeSourceResource);
        if (ret == null) {
            CodeSource cs = new CodeSource(classCodeSourceResource, (Certificate[]) null);
            DOMAIN_CACHE.add(new WeakReference<>(ret = new ProtectionDomain(cs, getPermissions(cs), this, null)));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private ProtectionDomain getCachedDomain(URL classCodeSourceResource) {
        for (WeakReference<ProtectionDomain> domainRef : DOMAIN_CACHE) {
            ProtectionDomain domain = domainRef.get();
            if (domain == null) {
                DOMAIN_CACHE.remove(domainRef);
            }
            else if (domain.getCodeSource().implies(new CodeSource(classCodeSourceResource, (Certificate[]) null))) {
                return domain;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**The "unsafe" code**

```
package com.example.untrusted;

public class Test {

    public static void testExitVm() {
        System.out.println("May I...?!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

**The entry point**

```
package com.example.trusted;

import java.security.AccessControlException;
import java.security.Permission;

import com.example.untrusted.Test;

public class Main {

    private static final Permission EXIT_VM_PERM = new RuntimePermission("exitVM.*");

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        try {
            Test.testExitVm();
        }
        catch (AccessControlException ace) {
            Permission deniedPerm = ace.getPermission();
            if (EXIT_VM_PERM.implies(deniedPerm)) {
                ace.printStackTrace();
                handleUnauthorizedVmExitAttempt(Integer.parseInt(deniedPerm.getName().replace("exitVM.", "")));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleUnauthorizedVmExitAttempt(int exitCode) {
        System.out.println("here let me do it for you");
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

}
```

#### Testing

**Packaging**
Place the loader and the main class in one JAR (let's call it `trusted.jar`) and the demo untrusted class in another (`untrusted.jar`).

**Assigning privileges**
The default `Policy` (`sun.security.provider.PolicyFile`) is backed by the file at `<JRE>/lib/security/java.policy`, as well as any of the files referenced by the `policy.url.n` properties in `<JRE>/lib/security/java.security`. Modify the former (the latter should hopefully be empty by default) as follows:

```
// Standard extensions get all permissions by default

grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// no default permissions

grant {};

// trusted code

grant codeBase "file:///path/to/trusted.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// third-party code

grant codeBase "file:///path/to/untrusted.jar" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "exitVM.-1", "";
};
```

Note that it is virtually impossible to get components extending the security infrastructure (custom class loaders, policy providers, etc.) to work properly without granting them `AllPermission`.

**Running**
Run:

```
java -classpath "/path/to/trusted.jar:/path/to/untrusted.jar" -Djava.system.class.loader=com.example.trusted.ClasspathClassLoader com.example.trusted.Main
```

The privileged operation should succeed.

Next comment out the `RuntimePermission` under `untrusted.jar`, within the policy file, and re-run. The privileged operation should fail.

As a closing note, when debugging `AccessControlException`s, running with `-Djava.security.debug=access=domain,access=failure,policy` can help track down offending domains and policy configuration issues.